# C - Does a variable declared in loop get the memory at same place each time the loop executes?

Tags: c, memory

Please read the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    char* a[4];
    int i=0;
    while(i<3)
    {
      char b[50];
      scanf(" %s",b);//Assume user enters one two three 
      a[i++]=b;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<3)
    printf(" %s ",a[i++]);//Why does it always print three three three
return 0;
}
```

Clarify the following:

1. Is it that b gets allocated same 50 bytes in memory each time so that all the elements of array a point to same 50 bytes and thus we get only three printed three times(i.e. what's entered last)
2. Since after the completion of while, array b can be removed very well but no it remains there every single time printing only three's. Why?
3. Is it not at all a coincidence that this code prints only three's when it could print one two three, one three three as well. What's wrong?

I know the question is very wrongly put. Forgive me for that. I am new here.

Comment: This looks very much like a series of questions a professor would ask a student, for that student to do research to find the answer.

Comment: @AntonH Might be. Believe me I’ve thought a lot on this. Those are issues I need clarification on.

Comment: 1. nope 2. undefined behaviour 3. yes, see answer to q 2 :-)

Comment: @MadhurPanwar The only thing to think about is the exact meaning of the language in the spec -- if it's specified. This isn't something you can determine from first principles.

Comment: @George Thanks. I have executed it so many times but the same output. Can you suggest a way so that I could get other possible outputs?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @ EdPlunkett Pardon. I didn't get you. Language in the spec?

Comment: "Is it not at all a coincidence" How do you know?

Answer (score 3):

**QUESTION #1:**

- The variable `b` is a variable that is strictly local to the 
  while loop.
- Therefore, do not reference via a pointer any memory formerly used by `b` outside (after) the while loop.
- Storage for `b` will be reallocated 3 times.
- At the end of the while loop, `b` will go out of scope.

**QUESTION #2:**

- After the while loop, `a` is not a valid pointer anymore
  because `a`  was assigned to point to `b`,
  and `b` has gone out of scope after the while loop.
- **NEVERTHELESS**, the memory allocated to `b` may still 
  not have been modified.  You cannot predict what the value of dereferencing `a` will be after the while loop - since `a` is only assigned based on `b`.

**QUESTION #3:**

- (Please see #2) The code that is dereferencing `a` after the while loop is using a stale pointer - I would not rely on the output.

Comment: Why all the double spacing?

Comment: Thanks, I removed the double spacing to make this easier to read

Comment: @AB Thanks a lot for the time.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question exhibits undefined behaviour because the second loop attempts to access the data that was only valid in the first loop.  Therefore, there is very little that can usefully be said.

The question title is "does a variable declared in a loop get the same address each time the loop executes".  Here's a proof by counter-example that the address of the variables in a loop need not always be the same, even in a single invocation of a non-recursive function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int n = rand() % 30 + 5;
        char a[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
            a[j] = rand() % 26 + 'a';
        a[n-1] = '\0';
        printf("a: %p %2d [%s]\n", (void *)a, n, a);
        char b[50+n];
        scanf("%s", b);
        printf("b: %p %2d [%s]\n", (void *)b, n+50, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (using GCC 7.1.0), one run of the program (`lv83`) produced:

```
$ ./lv83 <<< 'androgynous hermaphrodite pink-floyds-greatest-hits-dark-side-of-the-moon'
a: 0x7fff507e53b0 23 [sngrhgjganmgxvwahshvzt]
b: 0x7fff507e5360 73 [androgynous]
a: 0x7fff507e53c0  9 [wblbvifc]
b: 0x7fff507e5380 59 [hermaphrodite]
a: 0x7fff507e53b0 26 [pqsbfnnuxuldaactiwvjzvifb]
b: 0x7fff507e5360 76 [pink-floyds-greatest-hits-dark-side-of-the-moon]
$
```

The address at which the two arrays are allocated varies depending on how big they are.  By using different formulae for the sizes of the two arrays, the base addresses could be tweaked.  It looks as though the compiler rounds the base address of the arrays to a multiple of 16.